# Pincode mapping in Excel

Tags: excel, mapping

I need help in mapping pin codes in Excel. I have attached the sheet and have highlighted the result required. Can someone help me?

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Why your are using wild card here? You can `Vlookup()` full content.

Comment: can you please explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: The reason for mapping is, I would like to get the routing for delivery pin codes. I have used vlookup with partial match but that isn't working appropriately. The mapping pincode needs to match the pincode by considering the nearest possible match. Example for 603310 it has to map it to 603309 not 603301 and for 603311 it has to map it to 603312 not 603309